# How can I convert AWK script to one liner BASH command?

Tags: awk

I have the below AWK script file which works well if I call it from file such as

```
  awk -f conv-units.awk 53567782

  51.09 MB
```

`conv-units.awk`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{  x = ARGV[1]

        split("B KB MB GB TB PB",type)

    for(i=5;y < 1;i--)
        y = x / (2**(10*i))

    printf("%.2f %s\n",y,type[i+2])
}
```

But it fails when I ran it like :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ x = ARGV[1]   split("B KB MB GB TB PB",type)  for(i=5; y < 1; i--)   y=x/(2**(10*i))  {printf("%.2f %s\n",y,type[i+2])}}' 53567782
```

Comment: You have to separate commands with `;` (except for `for` `if` and alike)

Comment: why does it have to be one line?  Making code unreadable just so that you can say it's a "one liner" is a really bad move

Comment: I placed semicolons after each line, it won't work. I tried number of combinations.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It didn't work in my terminal. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 `bash version  5.0.17`

Comment: @jesse_b I want to run it in a pipe to measure internet usage. Like this : `</proc/net/dev grep -oP "wlp6s0"':\s*\K\d+' | awk '{x=$1; split("B KB MB GB TB PB",type); for(i=5;y < 1;i--) y = x / (2**(10*i)); printf("%.2f %s\n",y,type[i+2])}'`

Comment: Pipelines don't have to be one liners.

Comment: @jesse_b I didn't get what you mean. In which context? I use such one liners with pipe frequently.

Comment: @kenn it's not that a pipeline can't be a one liner, it's that it doesn't have to be, you can write clear, maintainable, multi-line code and still have it be part of a a pipeline.

Comment: @EdMorton OK. Thank you I got it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo 53567782 | awk '{x=$1; split("B KB MB GB TB PB",type); for(i=5;y < 1;i--) y = x / (2**(10*i)); printf("%.2f %s\n",y,type[i+2])}'
51.09 MB
```

Mind that I've replaced `x=ARGV[1]` with `x=$1`.

Comment: Thank you, it works well now. I didn't think that `x=ARGV[1]` would be an issue.

Comment: @kenn `x=ARGV[1]` isn't an issue if you want to set `x` to the value of the first argument passed to the script as in `awk 'script' foo` but now you want to pipe input to the script as in `echo foo | awk 'script'` so it'd make no sense to still be trying to set `x` to `ARGV[1]` when the value you're interested is now arriving in `$1`.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can pass that awk here as a function ? I have repeating code that use the same awk program, would be a good idea to have it in bash function.

Comment: @MaXi32 `function anyname() { awk '{}' }` only instead of x=$1; you need to have  `x='"$1"';`